# Using node how do I import my ES6-export-default module into my command line javascript program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I have an ES6 module in mymodule.js

```
export default function () {

  console.log('hello world');

}
```

Inside app.js, I import the module

```
import mymodule from 'mymodule'; //also tried './mymodule' and './mymodule.js'

mymodule();
```

Execute from the command line

```
node app.js
```

Or

```
node --experimental-modules app.js
```

Error message

```
import mymodule from 'mymodule';
   ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
at internal/modules/esm/translators.js:84:15
at Object.meta.done (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:40:9)
at file:///home/a/code/marionette/test_area/app.js:9:13
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:111:37)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:3)
```

**Versions**

```
node --version                                                                                                                                  
v12.0.0

npm --version
6.9.0
```

**Other**

- Linux
- using nvm
- Although I'm using npm and have a package.json file, I do not want to use babel or webpack or some other dev dependency to get this to work.
- I'm happy to use experimental features.

**Question**

Using node and ES6, how do I import an ES6 module into a command line javascript program?

Comment: [You have to be explicit about it.](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Pointy's comment, I made these changes

1. renamed mymodule.js to mymodule.mjs
2. changed to import to

   `import mymodule from './mymodule.mjs'`
3. in package.json added top level field

   `"type": "module",`